# Looping world for a top down space shooter?

Tags: unity, world-design

I am trying to understand how to make a seamless looping world for my top down space shooter.
First thing I tried was using multiple cameras, and teleporting the player when he reaches the edge, but it is not working well, and I don't like that I have to use 4 cameras.
I wanted to test making the objects in the world teleport around the player, but I will have problems with the fact that each object is a different size, and teleporting them around will for sure create problems with moving objects. (Big obstacles could be teleported away and not collide with, for example, bullets until the bullet gets teleported too but inside the big obstacle)
Are there other ways to accomplish this?
Screen of the game (everything is still a placeholder)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FWCE.png

Comment: Is your player moving or your landscape?

Comment: You might find some [previous Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/173589/39518) on related features useful. There's lots more if you type "wrap-around" into the search box.

Comment: @Zibelas The player is moving

Comment: @DMGregory I tried searching for terms like "loop" and never found anything useful. I will try with wrap-around, thanks!

Comment: It can also help if you show us a screenshot of your game, so we can understand things like whether the world is much much larger than what fits on screen, or if you can see all/most of it at a time. Knowing whether your obstacles are mostly stationary or moving, or whether they need physics simulation, can also help.

Comment: @DMGregory I added a screen but everything is a placeholder. Map is big, and currently I am using 4 cameras to show the other sides of the map, but I don't like that at all. Obstacles are static (planets) and moving (enemies, bullets). Player, enemies and bullets are rigidbodies and use physics to move.